# How can I fetch the data from firebase and store it on a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I fetch the data from firebase and store it on a list in flutter?

[image]

I want to get the data inside the document and store in a list into something just like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use,

```
 data.forEach(
    (key, value) {
      list.add(value);
    },
  );
```

where data is your map of the document.